# How can I optimize this order_by query in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following models:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    ...

class Popularity(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True)
    today = models.IntegerField(default=0, db_index=True)
```

I want to execute the following query:

```
movies = Movie.objects.order_by('-item__popularity__today') \
                      .values(...)
paginator = Paginator(movies, 12)
```

However, with about 52,000 rows in the database, this takes 500-700ms to run.  Is there any way to make this faster?  What I want to do is to get the 12 most popular movies in the database.

Comment: Try [limiting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) the QuerySet to 12 elements.

Comment: How does the `today` field work? If it's essentially a boolean value, you should be able to filter the queryset first, ex: `Movie.objects.filter('item__popularity__today'=1)` If not, perhaps there's another way to filter it first (`'item__popularity__today__gt'=0`, perhaps?)

Comment: How long does it take if you run the resulting query directly against the database?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you can do in Django. The way to optimize this is in the database.

Run `EXPLAIN` against the actual query that this generates - in fact, the Django debug toolbar can do that for you - and note whether the relevant subqueries and JOINs are using indexes, rather than full-table scans. You'll probably need to create an index for the Paginator table on `item, today` to start with.